# Windows doesnt see partition via console terminal

Tags: windows-10, command-line, partitioning, windows-explorer

I'm currently using dualboot windows 10 and ubuntu aswell. Since i use terminal alot in ubuntu, so it makes more problematic when it comes to windows. 
Just to make myself clear, i'd like to make a simple example.

From a point of view Windows, i have 2 partitions, on a same disk (there is also Linux partition, but windows wont show it)
`Local Disk C:\` and `Storage S:\`. Obviously, i store Windows OS on `C:\` while all documents are stored on `S:\`.

Now, if i have specific folder with documents (lets call it `abcd`) on a partition S:\, i just cant simply navigate it via `cd S:\` command, which forces me to use GUI variant instead.

Is there any solution for that? I really love CLI and I won't make everytime 'point-n-click' adventure in order to get what i want.

Thanks for responses

**UPDATE:** Attachment
[image: command line]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand you correctly - would it it be possible to do either one of the following from your cmd prompt:

> cd /d S:\

or just simply

> S:

Both of them should change the active working partition to S:\
which then in turn you would "cd" (change directory) in to.

To enter the exact path, you could use the above command together with the directory you want to access. Something in the lines of this:

> cd /d "S:\abcd"

Unfortunately the "cd" command does not support changing partition without specifying the "/d" flag as well.

Comment: yes, you get it correctly. And everytime it returns success without any changes

Comment: @Reborn I see! Could you please try all three examples, and add a screenshot of the result? It would make things a bit more clear.

Comment: Attachment has been added.

Comment: @Reborn - As you can see, the command I supplied is valid. The first one you tried "cd S:\" is not valid and will not work. This is how "cd" works. You have to use the "/d" flag if you want to switch partitions as well as directory. Combine that with the full path to enter a folder. The alternative you didn't try yet is just the partition letter "S:" with no "cd" or anything else in front. Which also should give you what you want.

Comment: just noticed, 's:' without 'cd' before works aswell too